# ReflectionUtil error in Component/Functional Test with Repository layer

Tags: spring, junit, spring-data-jpa, junit5

I am trying to run a JUnit test on my Repository layer

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {JPAConfig.class, SpringBootMainApplication.class})
public class AddBookTest {

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
    }


    @Test
    @Sql({"/book-schema.sql", "/book-data.sql"})
    void addBook() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.put("/users/")
                .header("X-MC-CorrelationID", UUID.randomUUID())
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .characterEncoding("UTF-8")
                .content("{\"book\": \"LOTR\"}")
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isNoContent())
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
    }


    private String requestBody() {
        return "{\n" +
                "  \"book\": \"LOTR\",\n" +
                "}";
    }


}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils$MethodFilter org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils$MethodFilter.and(org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils$MethodFilter)'
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension
```

Version:

```
implementation group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-web", version: "2.2.1.RELEASE"
implementation group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-data-jpa", version: "2.2.1.RELEASE"
implementation group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-actuator", version: "2.2.1.RELEASE"
testImplementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: "5.2.1.RELEASE"
implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: "5.2.1.RELEASE"
```

In short, all my Spring Boot dependencies are on **2.2.1.RELEASE** train while the Spring framework is **5.2.1.RELEASE**. Are these versions compatible?

Comment: These kind of errors come from the fact that you are mixing jars/modules from different versions of Spring. The fact that t you are using `@DataJpaTest` means you are using Spring Boot, the fact that you get this error means that you are messing around with dependencies which should be managed by sprig Boot. In short fix your dependencies.

Comment: Have updated my question with dependencies. I have also updated annotations to not include `@EnableJpaTest` annotation

Comment: Remove the `org.springframework` dependencies those mess up things. Also you have `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` twice, for testing add `spring-boot-starter-test` as a `implementationTest` dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to say for sure what happens but is sounds like a clash of versions of spring that you have on your classpath.

This specific method "and" is pretty new [see the javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils.MethodFilter.html). It explicitly states that the method is since version "5.3.2" which is pretty new.
So I suggest examining the dependency tree of jars in the test class path to understand whether you mix between a new and some older versions of Spring.

Comment: My Spring Framework version is *5.2.1.RELEASE*. There does not seem to be a version of 5.3.2 which is weird considering the error.